# Explicit bound for sum of Kloosterman sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

What are the best *fully explicit* upper bounds one can give for the sum
$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{S(a,b;n)}{n} \,I_1\!\left(\frac{4 \pi \sqrt{|ab|}}{n}\right) \right\lvert$$
where $S(a,b;n) = \sum_{\gcd(k,n)=1} e^{2 \pi i (ak+bk')/n}$ is the ordinary Kloosterman sum?

As a generalization one may consider any sufficiently regular function $f(C/n)$ instead of the Bessel function.

A trivial bound follows from using Weil's bound $|S(a,b;n)| \le \tau(n) \sqrt{\gcd(a,b,n)} \sqrt{n}$, plugging in an explicit bound for $\tau(n)$, and summing the series (see for example [Brisebarre and Philibert](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/nicolas.brisebarre/Publi/fujijrms.pdf)), but this is quite pessimistic.

The problem of bounding such sums is discussed in Sarnak and Tsimerman, [On Linnik and Selberg's conjecture about sums of Kloosterman sums](http://web.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/LinnikSelbergApr07.pdf). As far as I can tell, there are no published bounds (other than the trivial one) with fully explicit constants.

For motivation, see: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.14671